# Change column Year in R

Tags: r, date

I have an excel file, in the date column, it shows from 1/1/15 to 12/31/15. I want to change all 15(year) to 14, so that all Date looks like from 1/1/14 to 12/31/14. How to do that in R? Right now I just use replace function manually changed the date. But there are 150000 more records....

Comment: You want to change only for the year 2015?

Comment: it'll import as a string so just `gsub` it and convert to date after

Comment: it is very hard to help you if you do not provide a reproducible example nor a piece of your code nor a desired output.

Comment: As @rawr mentioned, `sub('14$', '15', v1)` would be one way

Comment: ...unless you have a source year with `Feb 29` in it, in which case you might get nonsense dates. `lubridate`'s `years()`  is safer.

Comment: I have a doubt whether this is all about changing 15 to 14 or not (based on the wording in your post).  Though, I asked that as a doubt earlier, it was not replied.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `lubridate` where you can just subtract 'x' number of years.

```
library(lubridate)

# some random 2015 dates
df <- data.frame(dates = mdy("01/13/2015", "02/25/2015"))

# subtract 1 year
df$dates <- with(df, dates - years(1))
df

       dates
1 2014-01-13
2 2014-02-25
```

Comment: You can subtract them using base R too. I also think there should be some condition here somewhere.

Comment: You should change the command to match the user's input. `mdy`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need !

Comment: @HeidiKaten glad it works, please accept the answer then so the question is closed.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to convert to 'Date' class and keep the same format, one option would be `sub`.  Here we match the last two characters that are 14 and replace it with 15.

```
 sub('14$', '15', v1)
 #[1] "1/1/15"   "12/31/15" "1/1/15"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c('1/1/15', '12/31/15', '1/1/14')
```

Comment: How does this work for subtracting a year from `Feb 29, 2016`?

Comment: @SerbanTanasa  We are not subtracting from 2016.  It is just replacing 15 with 14 if I understand the question.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa I could say the same about your answer. The OP did not specify the type of data so it could be time (improbable) but most likely character strings (from my point of view more probable)

Comment: I am just following the words in the post.  I know this would not work in all cases.  But, to me converting 15 to 14 was specific .